# Remove separated by characters special symbols from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to remove special symbols `/#$%^&*@0123456789` only if they are separated from each other by characters or symbols not in the list. For example:

```
H8e%&l6&%l@8095o a@/9^65$n228d w%e60$$#&9l3@/c6o5m3e --> Hello and welcome
. #$%#^ --> . #$%#^
,. a3%2%1/3$s*0. d8^! -->,. as. d!
I1^/0^^@9t #$%% i/@4#s 11P17/9$M 5^&* a^$45$5$0n&##^4d 6^&&* I $%^$%^ a8@@94%3*m t3120i36&^1r2&^##0e&^d ---> It #$%% is 11PM 5^&* and 6^&&* I $%^$%^ am tired
```

I know that simple string.replace will not work here. I tried something like this but it didn't work either:

```
 def _correct_message(message):
    f = re.match(r'[a-zA-Z][/#$%^&*@0123456789​][a-zA-Z]', message)
    if f is not None:
        message = re.sub('[/#$%^&*@0123456789​]', '', message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = "H8e%&l6&%l@8095o a@/9^65$n228d w%e60$$#&9l3@/c6o5m3e" 
s1 = "I1^/0^^@9t #$%% i/@4#s 11P17/9$M 5^&* a^$45$5$0n&##^4d 6^&&* I $%^$%^ a8@@94%3*m t3120i36&^1r2&^##0e&^d"
final_string = re.sub("(?<=[a-zA-Z\.\!])[/#\$\%\^\&\*\@0123456789]+(?=[a-zA-Z\.\!])", '', s) 
print(final_string)
new_final_string = re.sub("(?<=[a-zA-Z\.\!])[/#\$\%\^\&\*\@0123456789]+(?=[a-zA-Z\.\!])", '', s1)
print(new_final_string)
print(re.sub("(?<=[a-zA-Z\.\!])[/#\$\%\^\&\*\@0123456789]+(?=[a-zA-Z\.\!])", '', ',. a3%2%1/3$s*0. d8^!'))
```

Output:

```
'Hello and welcome'
It #$%% is 11PM 5^&* and 6^&&* I $%^$%^ am tired
,. as. d!
```

Comment: How to make it in string? Because if I run it like this it outputs list of characters and symbols. `s = ''H/2#e4$$&&0&l^2$l5o''` and `print(final_string)` will give `['H', '/', '2', '#', 'e', '4', '$', '$', '&', '&', '0', '&', 'l', '^', '2', '$', 'l', '5', 'o']`

Comment: `''.join(final_string)`

Comment: Yes, I did `join` but is still didn't remove symbols

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thanks it almost work fine only `,. a3%2%1/3$s*0. d8^!'` gives `,. as*0. d8^!` but should be  `,. as. d!`  
And I want to clarify what means `?<=` and why in the list of symbols some symbols are separated by `"\"`?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not exactly what you asked, but a first validation can be made based on .islapha() e.g:

```
 def validate(s):
    text=''
    for i in s:
        if i.isalpha():
            text+=i
        else:
          pass
     return text
```